# Where is better to use View Binding in Fragments? (onCreateView vs onViewCreated)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewbinding

I saw some examples where binding were defined and used in onCreateView() using inflate() and in onViewCreated() using bind().

What's the difference? And where is it better to operate with our views(RecyclerView, TextView and so on)?

Google documentation shows example like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
   inflater: LayoutInflater,
   container: ViewGroup?,
   savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
   _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
   val view = binding.root
   return view
}
```

But also in some articles we can see something like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.bind(view)
}
```

Comment: Can you share the link of google's documentation?

Comment: @Balaji sure, here it is - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good practice to use initialize binding in `onCreateview` as its will inflate the layout the same moment the view creates and then use this inside `onViewCreated` and other functions.

Also you need to make `_binding = null` in `onDestroyView` to prevent the leaks.

Comment: Also, I would say that using it with onCreateView removes the boilerplate to create the view and so on.

Comment: So if I inflated the layout in onCreateView, using binding.inflate, then I don't need to bind view in onViewCreated?

Comment: yes @MrArtyD in this case, you don't need to bind view in `onViewCreated`